# cLint.py: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: xcode

**/var/folders/r4//T/SchemeScriptAction.sh: /Volumes/Project/client_ios/build/../scripts/lint/objcLint.py: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**

I just update MacOS to Ventura 13.3 and Xcode 14.3. Every time when I am building or running app this error occurs.
Exited with status code 126.

I thought it is python issue so I installed python 3.8 but no luck.
How can I fix this issue.